# How to incorporate uncertainty and noise information in training and prediction of neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, recurrent-neural-network, uncertainty

I am trying to use RNNs to perform state estimation on noisy sensor data. The readings are from a GPS dataset and it provides $[longitude, latitude, n_{satellites}]$. The last column, which is the number of seen satellites, is indicative of how much should the state estimator "trust" the current reading.

I am trying to follow the same intuition from probabilistic filtering techniques like EKF, particle filters, etc. And this led me to a few questions;

In case the uncertainty of an observation is known:

- In a dataset (not necessarily time series data), can we use the extra information to regularize the training somehow using this extra piece of information ?
- In the specific case of state estimation, can we simply add that extra information about this uncertainty and the network should be able to learn that if the current observation has a large uncertainty then the prediction should almost neglect it ?

Any help would be very appreciated! Also if there are suggestions for other data driven approaches to perform state estimation! thanks!

Comment: Same question ! It would be great to have an answer !